# Install Azure deployment agent silently

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-pipelines

I have to install a deployment agent provided by azure on client machine.

But the tricky part is that when we deploy it manual it requires few steps like opening of PowerShell and the pasting of script and press enter 2 times.

I want this to be done silently like through automation as I am going to deploy this script on client machine with my existing window application as there are around 5k machine in which I have to install an agent and I can't do this manually.

Please suggest.

Comment: you mean azure devops agents? can you share the command ?

Comment: Yes I mean agent which are used to deploy you applications on the servers . For that in azure devops there is an option of deployment group where they provide you a PowerShell script that deploy an agent on the machines  where you fire the PowerShell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The agent can be set up from a script with no human intervention. You must pass --unattended and the answers to all questions.
>
> To configure an agent, it must know the URL to your organization or collection and credentials of someone authorized to set up agents. All other responses are optional. Any command-line parameter can be specified using an environment variable instead: put its name in upper case and prepend VSTS_AGENT_INPUT_. For example, VSTS_AGENT_INPUT_PASSWORD instead of specifying --password.
>
> Required options
>
> --unattended - agent setup will not prompt for information, and all settings must be provided on the command line
>
> --url  - URL of the server. For example: https://dev.azure.com/myorganization or http://my-azure-devops-server:8080/tfs
>
> --auth  - authentication type. Valid values are:
>   pat (Personal access token)
>   negotiate (Kerberos or NTLM)
>   alt (Basic authentication)
>   integrated (Windows default credentials)
>   Authentication options
>
> If you chose --auth pat:
>
> --token  - specifies your personal access token
>
> If you chose --auth negotiate or --auth alt:
>
> --userName  - specifies a Windows username in the format domain\userName or userName@domain.com
>
> --password  - specifies a password

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops#unattended-config

Comment: Can I increase the expiry date of PAT

Comment: Yes, but up to one year from today

Comment: Oh great how to make change for that because when I copy the script from deployment group with using PAT it expires with in one day

Comment: Hi @SahilKandroo if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Yes I will but can you tell how to increase the expire time of pat

Answer (score 3):

When running `.\config.cmd` with `--help` several examples are provided.

Below you can find two of them related to your case:

```
# Deployment group agent run as Windows service that logs on as Local System (Windows only)
    .\config.cmd --unattended --deploymentGroup --url https://myaccount.visualstudio.com --auth pat --token myToken --projectName myProject --deploymentGroupName myDeploymentGroup --agent myAgent --addDeploymentGroupTags --deploymentGroupTags "web, db" --runAsService --windowsLogonAccount "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"
    
# Deployment group agent with tags
    .\config.cmd --unattended --deploymentGroup --url https://myaccount.visualstudio.com --auth pat --token myToken --projectName myProject --deploymentGroupName myDeploymentGroup --agent myAgent --addDeploymentGroupTags --deploymentGroupTags "web, db" --runAsService --windowsLogonAccount "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" --acceptTeeEula
```

More info can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops).

Be aware that you must use [`--unattended`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts#unattended-config) for setting up from a script with no human intervention.

In case you happen to deal with self-hosted linux agent, check out the [unattended-config on linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=azure-devops#unattended-config):

```bash
./config.sh --help

./config.sh --unattended --url https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/ --auth pat --token myToken --projectName myProject --pool myAgentPoolName --agent myLinuxBuildAgent
```

Comment: And what about pat can’t I increase the expire time of PAT as I will expire with in one day and I don’t know how long it will take to fire this script

Comment: Event the deployment tag I remember when I use to deploy it manually I used to press enter for deployment tags do what this web , dB is

Comment: Would be great, if you added the sample commands for *nix as well.

Comment: @RajeshSwarnkar feel free to edit the answer

Comment: @AmitBaranes done, please approve changes !